# Set course teacher in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

what function could use to set course teacher
I used this to get course students or teachers

```
$context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_COURSE, course_id);
$students = get_role_users(5, $context);
```

but what in need is to set course teacher by a function

Comment: You want to give a user the role of teacher on a course?

Comment: @RussellEngland
Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a user a teacher role on a course

```
$coursecontext = context_course::instance($courseid);
$teacherroleid = $DB->get_field('role', 'id', array('shortname' => 'teacher'));
role_assign($teacherroleid, $userid, $coursecontext);
```

UPDATE: manually enrol a user on a course - this will also assign a role so you might not need the above code?

```
if (enrol_is_enabled('manual')) {
    // Ensure the manual enrolment plugin is enabled.
    $enrolplugin = enrol_get_plugin('manual');

    // Lookup the manual enrolment instance for this course.
    $instances = enrol_get_instances($this->course->id, true);
    foreach ($instances as $instance) {
        if ($instance->enrol === 'manual') {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($instance->enrol !== 'manual') {
        throw new coding_exception('No manual enrol plugin in course');
    }

    // Enrol the user with the required role
    $enrolplugin->enrol_user($instance, $userid, $roleid);
}
```

Comment: and how to enrol user in class please?